# Monadic predicate for takeWhileM function from the streaming library

Tags: haskell, streaming, monads

I'm trying to consume a stream of monadic values (produced by the `streaming` library) until a certain condition is met, but I'm having trouble writing a function which I can pass to `takeWhileM`.

I think I'm barking up the right tree, but I suspect that my signature of `stream` function could be wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack

import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import Data.Maybe

stream :: (Enum a, Num a, Monad m) => Stream (Of (Maybe a)) m ()
stream = S.takeWhileM predicate $ S.each $ [Just x | x <- [1..]]
  where
    predicate x = do
      x' <- x
      return $ x' < 5

main :: IO ()
main = do
  S.print stream
  print "done"
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
test.hs:8:10: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘Maybe’
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          stream :: forall a (m :: * -> *).
                    (Enum a, Num a, Monad m) =>
                    Stream (Of (Maybe a)) m ()
        at test.hs:7:1-64
      Expected type: Stream (Of (Maybe a)) m ()
        Actual type: Stream (Of (Maybe a)) Maybe ()
    • In the expression:
        S.takeWhileM predicate $ S.each $ [Just x | x <- [1 .. ]]
      In an equation for ‘stream’:
          stream
            = S.takeWhileM predicate $ S.each $ [Just x | x <- [1 .. ]]
            where
                predicate x
                  = do x' <- x
                       ....
    • Relevant bindings include
        stream :: Stream (Of (Maybe a)) m () (bound at test.hs:8:1)
  |
8 | stream = S.takeWhileM predicate $ S.each $ [Just x | x <- [1..]]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have also tried `predicate` like this and it didn't work (but I don't really want to be extracting the monadic value by hand, was hoping that `<-` could do some magic so that I can use this for other monads):

```
stream :: (Enum a, Num a, Monad m) => Stream (Of (Maybe a)) m ()
stream = S.takeWhileM predicate $ S.each $ [Just x | x <- [1..]]
  where
    predicate x = do
      x' <- x
      case x' of
        Just value -> return $ value < 5
        Nothing -> return $ False
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using any effect of the underlying monad `m` so the predicate doesn't need to be monadic, and `S.takeWhile` can be used instead.

```
  S.takeWhile predicate ...
  -- or S.takeWhileM (return . predicate)
where 
  predicate (Just x) = x < 5
  predicate Nothing = False
```

Comment: That works well, thank you. But is there a way for me to write this function in a more generic way to work with any monad? Like, if the stream was in `Either` monad for example.